# Numpy: how I can determine if all elements of numpy array are equal to a number

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I need to know if all the elements of an array of `numpy` are equal to a number

It would be like:

```
numbers = np.zeros(5) # array[0,0,0,0,0]
print numbers.allEqual(0) # return True because all elements are 0
```

I can make an algorithm but, there is some method implemented in `numpy` library?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can break that down into `np.all()`, which takes a boolean array and checks it's all `True`, and an equality comparison:

```
np.all(numbers == 0)
# or equivalently
(numbers == 0).all()
```

Comment: or use the builtin: `all(numbers==0)`

Comment: @bebop: Which is slower

Answer (score 23):

If you want to compare floats, use `np.isclose` instead:

```
np.all(np.isclose(numbers, numbers[0]))
```

Answer (score 4):

The following version checks the equality of all entries of the array without requiring the repeating number.

```
numbers_0 = np.zeros(5) # array[0,0,0,0,0]
numbers.ptp() == 0.0  # True

# checking an array having some random repeating entry
numbers_r = np.ones((10, 10))*np.random.rand()
numbers_r.ptp() == 0.0  # True
```

Comment: This fails with non-numerical dtype's

Answer (score -3):

`np.array_equal()` also works (for Python 3).

```
tmp0 = np.array([0]*5)
tmp1 = np.array([0]*5)

np.array_equal(tmp0, tmp1)
```

returns `True`

Comment: This is good but it unnecessarily creates a copy of the array.

Comment: Incorrect: for e.g. `[1, 0]` it should be False since `1 != 0`, but `[1, 0] == [1, 0]`. To be precise, this is a roundabout way of evaluating `a == a`, which is true iff `a` does not contain a `nan`

Comment: I don't see it as a solution

Answer (score -6):

Are numpy methods necessary? If all the elements are equal to a number, then all the elements are the same. You could do the following, which takes advantage of short circuiting.

```
numbers[0] == 0 and len(set(numbers)) == 1
```

This way is faster than using `np.all()`

Comment: I highly doubt that creating a hashtable of the array and looking up and inserting each element of a numpy array, that have to be fetched individually through the whole numpy + python call stack) is going to be faster than creating a boolean mask in numpy, and short circuited all-checking of that array also completely in numpy. Some `timeit` or plots of the scaling of your solution compared to numpy might be in order. `len(set(numbers))` doesn't short circuit at all, it needs to hash and compare each value to the existing set.